# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::SessionsController#create / Trying to Create 2 Signup Access with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i am new to rails and i apologise if the below issue may be a simple one but your help will be much appreciated.

I am using the GEM devise. I have an 2 authentication system setup (using devise) for Users(which represents Traders) & Homeowners

When a User signs in i want them to be directed to the users/show.html.erb page, when a homeowner signs in i want them to be directed to the homeowners/show.html.erb

**THE ERROR MESSAGE I GET:**

1. I have 2 devise 'after_sign_in_path_for' method in the
   application_controller.rb for user(Tradesman) & Homeowner
2. when i delete devise *after_sign_in_path_for* method for Homeowner
   and leave the coding devise *after_sign_in_path_for* method for User
   (Tradesman).....when i sign in as a User (Tradesman) i get no error
   and i am directed to the profile page (users/show.html.erb)...(vice
   versa).
3. but when i leave in both *after_sign_in_path_for* methods for User(Tradesman) & Homeowner and i sign in as either a User(Tradesman) or Homeowner i get the below error message

**I am trying to create two login access for User(Tradesman) & Homeowner**

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-07 14:59:36 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dI4uxvSE2tXlUeNlBCSLTbuvgRiUhdE5V1NfB8Y+htY=", "user"=>{"email"=>"richill@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Tradesman login"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'richill@gmail.com'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 7  [["current_sign_in_at", "2014-08-07 13:59:36.930831"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2014-08-07 13:57:07.157341"], ["sign_in_count", 7], ["updated_at", "2014-08-07 13:59:36.931472"]]
   (1.4ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 73ms

ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"homeowners", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:12:in `after_sign_in_path_for'
```

**views/homeowners/sessions/new.html.erb (this represents Homeowners login access)**

```
<h2>Are you a Homeowner?</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: false, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: false %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Homeowner login" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render "homeowners/shared/links" %>
```

**views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb (this represents Traders login access)**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <h1>Are you a Tradesman?</h1>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Tradesman login" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %></br>
```

**application_controller.rb - I believe the error is related here but unsure how to resolve it** when i comment out devise after_sign_in_path_for method for Homeowner & i sign in as a User (Tradesman) i get no error and i am directed to the profile page (users/show.html.erb). when i comment out devise after_sign_in_path_for method for User(Tradesman) & i sign in as a Homeowner i get no error and i am directed to the profile page (homeowners/show.html.erb). When i leave in both after_sign_in_path_for methods and i try to either sign in as a User(Tradesman) or Homeowner i get the above stated error

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_path(current_user)            #<--- For the Tradesman
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    homeowner_path(current_homeowner)  #<--- For the Homeowner
  end
end
```

**registration_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/user_steps'                          
    end

    def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:trade_id, :location, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :trade_id, :location, :title_id, :first_name, :last_name, :company_name, :company_number, :vat_number, :mobile, :business_role_id, :business_type_id, :employee_number_id, :card_name, :card_number, :card_date, :card_code, :role) }
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :homeowners
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
  resources :employee_numbers
  resources :business_types
  resources :business_roles
  resources :titles
  resources :form_signuptmas
  resources :homeowners
  resources :users
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/find', to: 'static_pages#find'
  get '/ask', to: 'static_pages#ask'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'home/index'
  resources :user_steps
  resources :jobs
  resources :trades
  root to: 'home#index', as: 'home'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't define 2 methods with the same name.  the second method will override the first.

if you look at the logs, you can see that there's a params passed to tell if a user is a tradesman or not

```
"commit"=>"Tradesman login"
```

so your method definition will look like

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if params[:commit] == 'Tradesman login'
    user_path(current_user)
  else
    homeowner_path(current_homeowner)
  end
end
```